# Flaky pattern-matching for Mittag-Leffler sums?

Tags: bugs, special-functions, summation

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier. Fixed in 12.2.0 or earlier.**

---

This sum correctly gives the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function):

```
Sum[z^k/Gamma[α*k + α], {k, 0, ∞}]
```

> MittagLefflerE[α, α, z]

Simply factoring the argument of `Gamma` makes the sum fail:

```
Sum[z^k/Gamma[α*(k + 1)], {k, 0, ∞}]
```

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{\text{Gamma}[(1+k)\alpha]}
> $$

What is happening? Why isn't this `Expand`/`Factor` transformation applied automatically by the pattern-matcher in order to effect the sum, as it is usually done for other sums, integrals, etc.?

---

update: reported & confirmed by WR.

Comment: The second form did not match any of the built-in pattern rules. Sometimes you can help Mathematica by manipulating the expression. In this case, use `ExpandAll`, i.e., `Sum[z^k/Gamma[\[Alpha]*(k + 1)] // ExpandAll, {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon that much is clear. What surprises me is how in this case (and only in this case as far as I remember working with Mathematica for many decades) the manipulations aren't done automagically. For all other sums, integrals, etc. I have a lot of freedom in how exactly I formulate the task; only for ML functions do I need to be that careful. So my question is: what is different about ML sums? Clarified the question, thanks.

Comment: You may use Sum[z^k/Gamma[ \ [Alpha]*(k + 1)], {k, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Regularization -> "Abel"]  (or any other method) to this end. Mma does not know that $\alpha$ is real.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the fact that `Sum` has the attribute `HoldAll`

Comment: @user64494 the conditioned sum `Assuming[α > 0, Sum[z^k/Gamma[α*(k + 1)], {k, 0, ∞}]]` doesn't work either. The `Abel` trick works though, thanks!

Comment: I'd report it to WRI.

Comment: @user64494 but it does assume it's positive. Try `Sum[z^k/Gamma[α*k + α], {k, 0, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's nice to see these things fixed in the new versions. I am using `13.2.0`

Edit: according to the comment by @kirma this is already fixed in `12.2`. Thanks for letting me know.

```
Sum[z^k/Gamma[α*k + α], {k, 0, ∞}]
Sum[z^k/Gamma[α*(k + 1)], {k, 0, ∞}]
```

> [image: res]

And a screenshot.

> [image: screen]

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 is the earliest I can run on my laptop without problems and I see these results already with it...

Comment: @kirma thanks for letting me know. I don't have access to `12.2` at the moment